Configuring mysql-apt-config endless loop
I'm installing mysql on a brand new Debian 12 VM, but I'm stuck while configuring "mysql-apt-config". This is probably something very easy but I'm not seeing it.
Step 1. I'm selecting MySQL Server & Cluster (Currently selected: mysql-8.4-lts). Then, using TAB, I'm switching to the OK button and hit enter.

Step 2. I'm selecting mysql-8.4-lts Then, using TAB, I'm switching to the OK button and hit enter.

Now I am returning at step 1...
No matter how I select things, which keys I use, if I navigate to OK or press enter immediately, it won't proceed past step 2.
Does anyone know how to make this installer accept my choices and continue with what it needs to do?

If that method isn't going anywhere, then why not just skip the step and use the config files?

apt install mysql-server -y returns "package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package. I'm not well versed with Linux operating systems. Just doing a one time install of debian with mysql following this guide: https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/install-mysql-on-debian/

If you are going to use a Linux distribution, then it helps if you have an understanding of it. That guide is for Debian 10 and 11 whereas you are using Debian 12. Unless this is an enterprise server in production, then the question is better on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. If that guide isn't working, then there are others including the MySQL site itself: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/linux-installation-apt-repo.html.

what is your cpu architecture? i am having the same issue with aarch64 also wanted to mention that this comment is completely false and totally unhelpful. this issue has nothing to do with the os.
"If you are going to use a Linux distribution, then it helps if you have an understanding of it."

I figured out a workaround... it's not pretty but i think it could be mostly copy/paste for you.
download this if you don't have it already
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb
extract and add the gpg key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C
if you'd like you can verify the key is added for mysql
apt-key list
update your package lists
sudo apt update
install mysql
sudo apt install mysql-server
